# buscar objeto de dentro de um array por valor de um atributo

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho dois arrays, um array possui o seguinte formato:

```
todasAsCartas:[
            { id: 1, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 5, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 9, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 13, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 17, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 21, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 25, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 29, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 33, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 34, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 35, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 37, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 38, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 39, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 41, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 42, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 43, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 45, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 46, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 47, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 49, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 50, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 51, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },

        ],
```

e o outro array é um array vazio, dessa forma:

```
cartasNaMao: [],
```

Eu tô precisando tirar um carta, que é um objeto de dentro da array "todasAsCartas" e enviar ele para o array "cartasNaMao".

Só que eu preciso buscar pelo id da carta. Já tentei fazer pelo indice do array mas só da erro.

O resto do código está aqui, estou usando o framework do Vuetify:

```
<template>

  <v-expansion-panel dark>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <template v-slot:header>
        <v-btn>
            <div>Start</div>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card height="400px"  full-width>

        <v-btn class="botaoEstilizado" @click="sacarCartaDoMonte">
            + 1
        </v-btn>

        <v-card class="ma-4" v-bind="numeroAleatorioGerado">
              <h3>Número aleatório gerado</h3>
            <p>
              {{ numeroAleatorioGerado }}
            </p>
        </v-card>

        <v-card class="ma-4" v-bind="cartasNaMao">
              <h3>Cartas na Mão</h3>
            <p>
              {{ cartasNaMao }}
            </p>
        </v-card>

        <!-- <v-btn class="botaoEstilizado" @click="mostrarCarta">
            Show
        </v-btn> -->

        <!-- abaixo está o codigo para importar imagem da carta  -->
        <!-- <v-img v-bind="umaCarta" :src="umaCarta.imgCarta" height="100px" width="100px" class="mx-4"></v-img> -->

        <div>
          <v-card class="ma-4" v-bind="baralho">
                <h3>Baralho</h3>
              <p>
                {{ baralho }}
              </p>
          </v-card>
        </div>

      </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>

</template>


<script>

export default {

    data: () => ({

        baralho: [],

        // Abaixo está o Código para importar uma imagem bindada com a tag v-img lá de cima do template
        // umaCarta: { "imgCarta": "https://i.ibb.co/7XsXX6G/doisdeouros.png" },

        numeroAleatorioGerado: [],

        todasAsCartas:[
            { id: 1, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 5, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 9, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 13, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 17, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 21, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 25, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 29, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 33, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 34, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 35, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 37, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 38, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 39, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 41, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 42, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 43, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 45, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 46, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 47, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 49, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 50, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 51, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },

        ],

        cartasNaMao: []

    }),

    mounted: function(){
        this.baralho = this.todasAsCartas;

    },

    methods: {

        removerCartaDoMonte(array, refId){

          array = this.todasAsCartas
          refId = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.todasAsCartas.length)
          console.log("this.todasAsCartas.length antes do for: " + this.todasAsCartas.length)
          console.log("1º console - refId antes, recebendo apenas o numero aleatorio: " + refId)

          for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
            if(array[i].id == refId){
              console.log('2º console -  entrei no if, ver qual o valor de refId após entrar no if: ' + array[i].id + ' = ' + refId);
              this.todasAsCartas.splice(array[i-1].id, 1);
              this.cartasNaMao.push(array[i - 1])
              console.log("this.todasAsCartas.length depois do for: " + this.todasAsCartas.length)
              break;

            }

          }

        },

        sacarCartaDoMonte(){
            this.removerCartaDoMonte();
        }

    }

}

</script>


<style>

.botaoEstilizado {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red;

}

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você deveria ter postado o erro que aparece pra você.

Removendo toda a parafernalha do framework, o seu código funciona no meu navegador sem erros, a não ser quando o número aleatório é zero. Mas tem algumas coisas no seu código que não fazem sentido pra mim:

Porque você passa e recebe o `refId', se ao invés de usar o valor dele, você vai jogar um valor aleatório nessa variável?
Pra que você percorre o`for`atrás do`refId`, se você pode simplesmente usar o`refId` como índice do array?

Sugiro que você faça testes sem esse framework, seja numa página do seu servidor web ou no JSFiddle.

Comment: Amigão, mas ele não dá erro no console. Ele dá erro porque ele exclui errado. Pelo método splice lá (this.todasAsCartas.splice(array[i-1].id, 1), quando eu passo array na posição i ponto id para ele para deletar, ele passa um numero (number), como parâmetro, e não deveria. Como eu preciso que ele exclua exatamente o id de número 34, por exemplo, eu preciso que seja passado um parametro que fale pra ele buscar no array quem dos objetos tem esse id e aí sim excluir esse objeto inteiro, de acordo com esse id dele de número 34. Eu posso detalhar mais, whatsapp (67)991704717

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar uma lista que recebe apenas os IDs das cartas que estão na mão e uma propriedade computada que vai renderizar todas as cartas filtradas com base nos IDs incluídos na lista que citei inicialmente

```html
<template>
  <v-expansion-panel dark>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <template v-slot:header>
        <v-btn>
            <div>Start</div>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card height="400px"  full-width>

        <v-btn class="botaoEstilizado" @click="sacarCartaDoMonte">
            + 1
        </v-btn>

        <v-card class="ma-4" v-bind="numeroAleatorioGerado">
              <h3>Número aleatório gerado</h3>
            <p>
              {{ numeroAleatorioGerado }}
            </p>
        </v-card>

        <v-card class="ma-4" v-bind="cartasNaMao">
              <h3>Cartas na Mão</h3>
            <p>
              {{ cartasNaMao }}
            </p>
        </v-card>

        <!-- <v-btn class="botaoEstilizado" @click="mostrarCarta">
            Show
        </v-btn> -->

        <!-- abaixo está o codigo para importar imagem da carta  -->
        <!-- <v-img v-bind="umaCarta" :src="umaCarta.imgCarta" height="100px" width="100px" class="mx-4"></v-img> -->

        <div>
          <v-card class="ma-4" v-bind="baralho">
                <h3>Baralho</h3>
              <p>
                {{ baralho }}
              </p>
          </v-card>
        </div>

      </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>

</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: () => ({

        baralho: [],

        // Abaixo está o Código para importar uma imagem bindada com a tag v-img lá de cima do template
        // umaCarta: { "imgCarta": "https://i.ibb.co/7XsXX6G/doisdeouros.png" },

        numeroAleatorioGerado: [],

        todasAsCartas:[
            { id: 1, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 2, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Copas'   },  { id: 3, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Espadas'   },  { id: 4, 'valor': 2, 'naipe': 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 5, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 6, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Copas'   },  { id: 7, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Espadas'   },  { id: 8, 'valor': 3, 'naipe': 'Ouros'   },
            { id: 9, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Paus'   },  { id: 10, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 11, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 12, 'valor': 4, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 13, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 14, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 15, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 16, 'valor': 5, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 17, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 18, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 19, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 20, 'valor': 6, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 21, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 22, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 23, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 24, 'valor': 7, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 25, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 26, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 27, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 28, 'valor': 8, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 29, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Paus'  },  { id: 30, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Copas'  },  { id: 31, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Espadas'  },  { id: 32, 'valor': 9, 'naipe': 'Ouros'  },
            { id: 33, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 34, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 35, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 36, 'valor': 10, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 37, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 38, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 39, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 40, 'valor': 11, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 41, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 42, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 43, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 44, 'valor': 12, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 45, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 46, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 47, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 48, 'valor': 13, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },
            { id: 49, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Paus' },  { id: 50, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Copas' },  { id: 51, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Espadas' },  { id: 52, 'valor': 14, 'naipe': 'Ouros' },

        ],

        cartasNaMaoID: [
          41, 51, 51
        ]

    }),
    
    computed: {
      listaCartasNaMao () {
        const { cartasNaMaoID } = this;

        return this.todasAsCartas.filter(carta => cartasNaMaoID.includes(carta.id))
      }
    },

    mounted: function(){
        this.baralho = this.todasAsCartas;

    },

    methods: {

        removerCartaDoMonte(array, refId){

          array = this.todasAsCartas
          refId = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.todasAsCartas.length)
          console.log("this.todasAsCartas.length antes do for: " + this.todasAsCartas.length)
          console.log("1º console - refId antes, recebendo apenas o numero aleatorio: " + refId)

          for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
            if(array[i].id == refId){
              console.log('2º console -  entrei no if, ver qual o valor de refId após entrar no if: ' + array[i].id + ' = ' + refId);
              this.todasAsCartas.splice(array[i-1].id, 1);
              this.cartasNaMao.push(array[i - 1])
              console.log("this.todasAsCartas.length depois do for: " + this.todasAsCartas.length)
              break;

            }

          }

        },

        sacarCartaDoMonte(){
            this.removerCartaDoMonte();
        }

    }

}

</script>


<style>

.botaoEstilizado {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red;

}

</style>
```

agora a propriedade `listaCartasNaMao` vai conter a referência das cartas baseadas na lista `cartasNaMaoID` que será onde você precisará fazer a manipulação

Espero ter ajudado